Minimum singular value vs condition number to determine closeness to singularity
Which criteria should I use to determine if a matrix is close to singularity or not?
My application is to try to find an optimal matrix that maximizes the minimum singular value/minimizes the condition number such that the matrix is well-conditioned and far from singularity.
I found these two quantities are not necessarily correlated:

when I try to maximize the minimum singular value, the maximum singular value can also be high, resulting in a high(bad) condition number.
when I try to minimize the condition number, the optimal condition number can be as small as 1 but the singular values are identically(because the condition number is 1) small.

